# Are Arduino inputs equivalent to voltage measurement?

Tags: voltage-measurement, basic

I read somewhere that Arduino input pins basically (more or less) just measure the voltage at their pins with respect to ground (and then, based on that, create an analogue value or a digital HIGH or LOW reading). Would that mean that the following two circuits are equivalent with regard to voltage measurement?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Would that mean that the following two circuits are equivalent with regard to voltage measurement?

Measurement, not really, but essentially, yes, volts must change for the input to change.

The details though, are quite a bit more complicated than that.

If the pin is set to an *analog input*, then whatever voltage present on the pin is converted to a digital value by an internal component called a ADC or analog-to-digital-converter.  0V typically gets a value of 0, while the maximum volts is set to a value limited by the number of bits of resolution the ADC has.  An 8-bit ADC can output a value up to \$2^8\$ or 0-255, so max-volts would get a value of 255 in that case.

If the pin is set to a *digital input*, then voltages over some threshold like 2.2V are considered "high" or "1", while voltages under some other threshold like 1.8V are considered "low" or "0".  Due to the way these circuits are constructed, the in-between voltage range is generally a no-go area, where the internal components will draw excessive current and could possibly be damaged if left that way for too long.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the top circuit only measures two levels.

The second circuit measures in much finer resolution.

For the top circuit to be equivalent to the second circuit, the top circuit would need to be an ADC pin, and not a normal digital input (general purpose IO, GPIO) pin.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda, with the caveat that digital inputs can't measure the actual voltage, only tell you whether it is close to 5V or close to 0V.

Yes, the digital input tells you 1 (HIGH) if the voltage is close to 5V, and 0 (LOW) if it's close to 0V. An analog input actually measures the voltage and gives you a number that can be used to calculate the voltage.

Note that in-between voltages on digital pins are not allowed, except for short periods of time when the voltage changes from one to the other. In-between voltages can waste power because, as an over-simplification, they can activate both the 1 circuit and the 0 circuit in the chip, causing them to fight against each other. In extreme cases this can damage those circuits by overheating them. I've never heard of this actually happening to an Arduino, but it's a theoretical possibility.

---

*Arduinos don't*, but some chips such as TTL chips have inputs that source (push out) or sink (pull in) significant amounts of current. In this case it is not possible to say whether they are measuring voltage or current, because voltage and current happen together. Some chips (not sure which) might even have current inputs, where the chip keeps the voltage the same and senses the direction of the current instead.